# How would i draw a graph given a specific degree sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example, I have a degree sequence (4,3,3,1,1,1,1) and I want to draw its graph. I know that it will have 7 edges, put I can't seem to put the graw together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following graph has the desired properties.
[image]

Comment: how would i do this for other degree sequences? i.e. 5,3,3,3,1,1... is it just guess and check, or is there a method i could be using?

Comment: Place the points on your page, start with the vertex with largest valency and keep joining them up until you have a graph with the given degree sequence. Trial and error will quickly get you an answer in these small examples.